# Installing the libs3 on linux

Tags: linux, linker, gnu-make, libs

Could someone pls give me a detailed procedure to intsall libs3 on LINUX? Just the procedure will do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i used the gcc s3.c -I../inc -L../build/lib/ -ls3 -lcurl -lxml2 command, but the files are still not being linked. And i would also like to know what to do after linking the files.

Comment: First of all, add more details by edditing the question, not by posting a comment. Second, please mention what kind of linux os are you using. Third, try to consider that your question may be more suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://askubuntu.com/ .

Comment: Its different for different linux distros.
You will find more information in the README.

Answer (score 1):

These are the instructions to install libs3 on centos on a 64 bit machine.

According to their README, you are supposed to build an rpm package out of their source code using 'rpmbuild -ta '

1.) So first, install rpmbuild if it isn't installed already. [My install location is the default one:  ~/rpmbuild]

2.) Clone libs3.

```
git clone https://github.com/bji/libs3.git
```

3.) Rename folder as libs3-trunk [rpmbuild complained if its name wasn't that, so...], create a tar.gz, copy it to SOURCES folder inside rpmbuild directory.

```
mv libs3 libs3-trunk
tar -zcvf libs3-trunk.tar.gz libs3-trunk/
mv libs3-trunk.tar.gz ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES
cd ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES
```

4.) Build the rpm

```
rpmbuild -ta libs3-trunk.tar.gz
cd ../RPMS/x86_64
```

5.) Install dependency libs3-2-2.0-5.1.x86_64.rpm from 
[http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/21900926/dir/centos_6/com/libs3-2-2.0-5.1.x86_64.rpm.html] OR [ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/dalgaaf:/ceph:/extra/CentOS_CentOS-6/x86_64/libs3-2-2.0-5.1.x86_64.rpm]

6.) Install the rpm:
Execute following as sudo:

```
rpm -Uvh libs3-2-2.0-5.1.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh --replacefiles libs3-trunk-1.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh libs3-devel-trunk-1.x86_64.rpm
```

7.) Install libcurl-devel/libxml2-devel through yum if you get following error:
make: curl-config: Command not found
make: xml2-config: Command not found

```
sudo yum install libcurl-devel.x86_64
sudo yum install libxml2-devel.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu versions >=14.04, libs3-dev is available as an Ubuntu package.

So you just need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install libs3-dev
```